# When should I use type bound in generic class in scala?

Tags: scala, generics

I have a generic class like this and I only want function "one" to be called when T is Int.

```
class A[T] {
    def one[T <: Int] = 1
}
val a = new A[String]
a.one
```

But this compiles.

I find that I can do this:

```
class A[T] {
    def one(implicit ev: T <:< Int) = 1
}
val a = new A[String]
a.one
<console>:14: error: Cannot prove that String <:< Int.
```

Why?

Answer (score 3):

In the first case you have two *different and unrelated* `T` parameters: one on the class, another on the method. So when you call `a.one`, `one`'s `T` is `Int`.

In the second case `one` doesn't have its own `T` parameter, so in `T <:< Int` you have `A`'s `T`. When you call `a.one`, `A`'s `T` is `String` which doesn't satisfy the bound.